# Durandal multiple V/VM for route

Tags: durandal

I am creating an app using durandal.  The basic premise is

The header always using the the same V/VM with different data based on the route while the data V/VM will change based on that navigation

I have the data section changing via the router no problem.  I can't get the header section to consistently activate so I can change it.

I have tried using an activator and call activate on router.onNavigationComplete, but it doesn't always call the activate function in my viewModel.

Can somebody point me in the right direction to get this working correctly?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use *activate: true*. look at the following:

```
<div>
   <div data-bind="compose:'views/header.html', activate: true"></div>
</div>
```

Please refer to: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/